# htaccess if no query_string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string

Is it possible to have something like.

```
IF ! ${QUERY_STRING} no-cache=1
<load mod_gzip>
END IF
```

I am trying to allow cache-busting across our dev environment if there is a query_string of no-cache=1

Comment: What Apache version do you have? The `<If>` core directive in 2.4 should be able to do this. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
# enable compression for all requests
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

RewriteEngine On

# disable gzip compression is ?no-cache=1 is set in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^no-cache=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
```